# Prosody XMPP server says that A record points to unknown address

Tags: linux, networking, dns, fedora, xmpp

I am setting up an XMPP Server (Prosody) on noisytoot.org.

I am running Fedora Server 30.

I have setup an A record on xmpp.noisytoot.org, and SRV records for noisytoot.org.

The config file for noisytoot.org (/etc/prosody/conf.d/noisytoot.org.cfg.lua):

```lua
VirtualHost "noisytoot.org"
```

Prosody fails to start and says that xmpp.noisytoot.org does not resolve to this server, xmpp.noisytoot.org points to 2.29.34.180, which is the IP address of my network, and points to the server

Here is the output of `sudo prosodyctl check`:

```
Checks will be skipped for these disabled hosts: example.com

Checking config...
Done.

Checking DNS for host localhost...
    Target 'localhost' cannot be accessed from other servers

Checking DNS for host noisytoot.org...
    xmpp.noisytoot.org. A record points to unknown address 2.29.34.180
    Host xmpp.noisytoot.org. does not seem to resolve to this server (IPv4/IPv6)
    No targets for noisytoot.org appear to resolve to this server.


For more information about DNS configuration please see https://prosody.im/doc/dns

Checking certificates...
Checking certificate for localhost
  Certificate: /etc/pki/prosody//localhost.crt
    Not valid for client connections to localhost.
    Not valid for server-to-server connections to localhost.
Checking certificate for noisytoot.org
  Error: No certificate present in SSL/TLS configuration for noisytoot.org

For more information about certificates please see https://prosody.im/doc/certificates

Problems found, see above.
```

Comment: I've found that `prosodyctl check` does not resolve `CNAME` records, it checks directly only for `A` and `AAAA` [here](https://github.com/bjc/prosody/blob/0eedd1130fe9eb7379c427d1fa1a8f7e9e715a6f/util/prosodyctl/check.lua#L374-L425). This was the reason I got `does not seem to resolve to this server (IPv4/IPv6)`. However, you say to be using `A` directly, so that might not the explanation for your error.